# How can I iterate through a 'servers' object in OpenAPI .yaml file using javascript

Tags: javascript, yaml, openapi

The servers object look something like this:

```
servers:
- description: Development server
  url: https://development.gigantic-server.com/v1
- description: Staging server
  url: https://staging.gigantic-server.com/v1
- description: Production server
  url: https://api.gigantic-server.com/v1
```

I have to basically iterate through the servers object to find out if the child object with description "Production server" exists or not.

I am not sure as to how iterating in yaml file is done on a specific object (servers in this case).

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far? What OpenAPI or YAML parser are you using to read the file?

Comment: Hi @Helen, So my code looks like this:                   
                  `const specFile = YAML.parse(yamlFile); client = await Swagger({ spec: specFile }); client.spec.servers.find((obj) => obj.description === "Production server");`.

Comment: Instead of using `find`, I want to iterate through the servers object and match the description I'm looking for and if it doesn't exists, I then want to throw a customised error, right now, with the current code setup, if 'production server' doesn't exists, it tries to find and read the value of `obj.description` and since the desired description doesn't exists, it throws an error - "cant read the value of undefined"